# laravel slug not working-Attempt to read property "slug" on null

Tags: laravel

I am trying to generate slug in my URL instead of id. But I am getting this error message on my laravel window when I click on "**Edit**"----

"**Attempt to read property "slug" on null**"

in my web.php--

```
Route::get('/edit-client/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\backend\ClientController::class, 'EditClient'])->name('EditClient');
Route::post('/update-client/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\backend\ClientController::class, 'UpdateClient'])->name('UpdateClient');
```

in my model "OurClient.php" --

```
class OurClient extends Model{
use HasFactory;
protected $guarded = [];
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

}
in my Controller --

```
public function editClient($slug)
{
    $clients = OurClient::find($slug);
    return view('backend.clients.edit',compact('clients'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function updateClient(Request $request, $slug)
{   
            OurClient::find($slug)->update([
            'clientName' => $request->clientName,
            'slug'        => Str::slug($request->clientName),
            'companyName' =>$request->companyName,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'designation' => $request->designation,
            
    ]);
    return Redirect()->back();  
}
```

in my index.blade.php--

```
<a href="{{ route('EditClient',['slug' => $client->slug]) }}" type="button">Edit</a>
```

in my edit.blade.php---

```
<form action="{{ route('UpdateClient',$clients->slug) }}" method="POST"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        @method('patch')
                        <input type="hidden" name="old_image" value="{{ $clients->photo }}">
                                <div class="row">

                                    ...
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit">Update Client</button>

                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `OurClient::find($slug)` try using  `OurClient::where('slug',$slug)->first()`

Comment: it's showing "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'martina-howard' in 'where clause'. it's taking input slug value as a column
"

Comment: Sorry typo mistake, but what key are you using for slug in DB ?

Comment: solved it. it's OurClient::where('slug', $slug)->first(). Thanks a lot man